# XQuery: Access value in node

Tags: xquery

I have text-input-boxes on a website which I´m accessing via XQuery. Something like this on the website:

```
<input id="input1" type="text" value="300">
```

I need to access the "value" fields, but I´m missing the idea here how to do this.

Here´s the code I´ve tried:

```
let $doc := html:parse(fetch:binary('websiteaddress'))
return
<datarow>
<input1>{data($doc/html/body/div/div/div/div/div)}
</input1>
</datarow>
```

As result I get all the description text on the website, but not the fields itself.

At the end I would need datarows with the "value". So I guess I have to do something like $doc//div[@id="input1"]?....but how to access the value?

Any ideas on that?

Comment: $doc//div[@id="input1"]/@value

Answer (score 0):

You can access the attribute values with the attribute axis.

Most people use the [abbreviated syntax](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#path-abbrev) `@`:

```
$doc//input[@id="input1"]/@value
```

but you can also use `attribute::`:

```
$doc//input[@id="input1"]/attribute::value
```

Comment: pls see below, thx

Comment: whoops, I wasn't paying close enough attention to your original XPath. The element that has these attributes is the `input` element, not a `div`. I updated the XPaths in my answer. Also, the info you had posted as an answer should be added to the question, or deleted. What you posted is not an answer.

Comment: If the input is always a child of div, you could also use `$doc//div/input[@id="input1"]/@value` or even a more explicit XPath to avoid the `//` which should perform better. The main point though is that if you want to address the `@value` attribute, add that last step to point to it.